# File size while hitting direct link from Android Application

Tags: android, android-intent

In my Android application I am having an option to download an another application (apk file). The Application is of around 3MB file so user needs to wait until the download will complete.

**How it is implemented in my application**

In my application there is a button when user taps on that button it is hitting a url of apk file directly provided by my application server.

Now for user convenience I want to show the size of application and progress of download but I am not getting how to find the size of application while I am hitting the url directly for downloading?

Comment: Although i know it is possible because when I am hitting that urlfrom desktop browser then it is giving me the size so why not through code.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a real late answer, but if using `HTTP` for your download, you can send a `HEAD` request to retrieve information from the file.
Then use the `GET` to retrieve the content.